# How to make scrolltop() functionality work with Mmenu

Tags: jquery, offset, scrolltop, mmenu

I am using the jQuery mmenu to add an off-canvas menu to my site. Before installing it I had a scroll-to-top button and a slide-down navigation bar that relied on getting the offset from `$(window).scrollTop();` to trigger them. I've noticed that mmenu seems to have hindered the ability to find the offset of the window. When I ran the following code:

```
var offset = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function(){

     console.log(offset);
});
```

and, checked Chrome DevTools' console, I noticed that while it does output the offset, there seems to be an overriding offset that's set to 0, regardless of the visual position of the window and scrollbar.

I tried finding the offset of other elements instead, but I still wind up getting the same output in the console.

Ultimately, what I'd like to be able to do is have my scroll-to-top button and slide-down navigation bar triggered after the user scrolls down.

My code for them is as follows:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    /* slide-down navigation bar */

    if($('.bar').css('z-index') == '30' && offset > 50 ){

        $('#secondary-nav-wrap').addClass('slideDown');

    }else{

        $('#secondary-nav-wrap').removeClass('slideDown');
    }

    /* fade in jump to top button */

    if (offset >= 200) {

        $('#top-jump').fadeIn(400);
    }else{

        $('#top-jump').fadeOut(400);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your offset variable is initialized at the loading of the page and doesn't change. That's why it's always 0.

Do:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
     console.log(offset);
});
```